# Glimpse.Ado issue with missing "CreatedOn" column in EF schema

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, glimpse

I'm using the latest bits.

When I initialise my EF data context, I get `An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in Glimpse.Ado.dll but was not handled in user code.`

The exception detail is

- Either `The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = c,Column name = CreatedOn ]`. But the `CreatedOn` column isn't used anymore by EF Migrations.
- Or `The specified table does not exist. [ __MigrationHistory ]`. But it does.

This seems to happen only in debug mode, and interestingly, if I just "continue", it sometimes moves past the exception and everything else works. But, it ruins every debug build and every debug session.

Without Glimpse, everything works. What should I do?

Comment: Is this just happening on startup? And is it just reporting the exception in the SQL tab or is it throwing an exception?

Comment: @anthonyv Yes on startup, it usually prevents the app from loading at all. It doesn't report anything.